# C# count timer wont stop counting

Tags: c#

Its a goldminer game, when the anchor catch a gold and drag it to the surface, the gold should disappear and count increase, but since I'm using a timer to move the gold in my code it start counting when the Anchor touch a gold and stop when the gold disappear at the surface in this period of time the count keep increasing, I'm trying to make it count only when the gold disappear at the surface.

What should I do to make it count once every time a gold dissapear.

```
private void goldtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB1, ref Scorecount);
  score.Text = " " + Scorecount;
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB2, ref Scorecount);
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB3, ref Scorecount);
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB4, ref Scorecount);
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB5, ref Scorecount);
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB6, ref Scorecount);
  move.goldmove(ref AnchotPB, ref goldPB7, ref Scorecount);
}

class move
{
  public static void goldmove(ref PictureBox Anchor, ref PictureBox Gold, ref int count)
  {
    int speed = 15;
    if ( Anchor.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Gold.Bounds) && Anchor.Top > 119 )
    {
      Gold.Top -= speed;
      Anchor.Top -= speed;
    }

    if ( Anchor.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Gold.Bounds) && Anchor.Top == 119 )
    {
      Gold.Visible = false;
    }

    if ( Anchor.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Gold.Bounds) && Gold.Visible == true )
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't stop the timer cuz if I do I cant catch other gold pieces, I want it to stop counting after catching a gold piece

Comment: it looks like you're incrementing count every time the method is called and the gold is still visible. since you ask, *"What should I do to make it count once every time a gold dissapear"*, it seems like just incrementing count once when you set `Gold.Visible = false` should do the trick?